# can't use mixpanel with eclipse on android

Tags: android, mixpanel

I try to put mixpanel in my android project. But it  gives me error:

> BuildConfig.MIXPANEL_VERSION cannot be resolved or is not a 
>        field

The problem is in the file

> com.mixpanel.android.BuildConfig

it is in the gen directory:

```
/** Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY */
package com.mixpanel.android;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

so any ideas how to fix this problem and include the mixpanel lib in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue in library release 4.5.0, but should be fixed in the current version of the library. You'll need to download the latest tag from the Mixpanel for Android github repo, here: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/releases/tag/latest